# Sporadic Error Window when using DirectShow with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, directshow.net

I have build an app which shows two direct show graphs in parallel. This application uses WPF, therefore I evaluated different solutions, like WPFMediaKit (http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) and AVCapWPF(https://wpfcap.codeplex.com/).

Both solutions normally works fine. But sometimes i get a grey error window (which looks a lot like Windows 2000) with some information about CPU (but old CPU information, seems like the actual CPU was not known, when this error message was designed) and loaded Dlls, but no error message at all. The title of the window is simply "Error".

The problem is the error occurs sporadically, so I am not sure, whether I know all occurrences, but the following error cases are known:

1. Error occurs somewhere when building the direct show graph which results in only one graph loaded and displays
2. Error occurs before both graphs were built, which results in both graphs loaded and displayed
3. Error does not depend of the used filter in the graph. For rendering the frameworks uses different renderer and the source filter where switched as well, mostly using Montivision DemoSource.

I could only produce the error when both graphs were rendered but could also not find a possibility to produce it regularly.

When the error window is closed, the whole application is finished (crashed). It is impossible to catch the error in .Net. It seems like it comes from a system library.

Error Window Text:

```
OS:  Workstation, SP1
CPU: GenuineIntel, Intel Pentium III Xeon, MMX @ 2490 MHz

Module name: D:\[...]\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe

Application data:
VmVyc2lvbjogV2t4dGJIZHFVbTEyYkdsb0oxRmhiR3htS2xwaWUya3N
TMlJpZW1wOVRUd3hTaU0rTXlJNE5DTTVOaVpLT3pnVkUwSXJOQzRxUE
... (a base64 encoded list of loaded dlls)
```

I hope someone knows that error and a good solution for avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run app on clean Windows installation and without Montivision etc. usage?

Also, please show list of used DLL's and graph screenshot.

Comment: I tried different installations (and different hardware) of Window7, even new ones.

Comment: Montivision is used in nearly every graph, because they provide most of the basic filters I need, like hardware independent demo source for testing. The list of loaded dlls contains 174 entries. Using AVCapWPF no graph was needed (the graph build inside is DemoSource -> SampleGrabber, with WPFMediaKit the Graph is DemoSource -> VideoMixingReneder9.